# Finding the area between two curves and my attempt

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Question is to find the area between two curves given by $r=1$ and $r^{2} = \cos(2\theta)$ and the $\theta$ bounds are from $0$ to $\pi/2$.

$$\begin{align}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{1}^{\sqrt{\cos 2\theta}} r \ dr\  d\theta &=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos 2 \theta\ -1\  d\theta \\&=\frac{1}{2}\Bigg[\frac{\sin 2 \theta}{2} - \theta\Bigg]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\\&=\frac{1}{2}\Bigg[-\frac{\pi}{2} - 0\Bigg]\\=& -\frac{\pi}{4}\end{align}$$

If I am correct,why is the answer coming negative?

Comment: You have two mistakes. $\sqrt{\cos(2\theta)}$ is imaginary for $\theta \in (\pi/4,\pi/2]$ and $1 > \sqrt{\cos(2\theta)}$ on $[0,\pi/2]$.

Comment: @achillehui can you please elaborate how should i do

Comment: Split the integral into two pieces, $$\int_0^{\pi/4} \int_{\sqrt{\cos(2\theta)}}^1 \cdots + \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \int_0^1 \cdots $$ the rest should be straight forward.

Comment: How have you splitted up integral

Comment: When $\theta \in (\pi/4,\pi/2]$, the RHS of $r^2 = \cos(2\theta)$ is smaller than zero. This means for such $\theta$, the lower bound of your integral over $r$ is $0$ instead of an imaginary number $\sqrt{\cos(2\theta)}$.

Comment: I have understood about splitting bere , but why you have taken zero as lower bound

Comment: The constraint $1 \ge r^2 \ge \text{-ve number} $ is equivalent to $1 \ge r \ge 0$ because $r$ are non-negative!

Comment: @achille hui In your first integral why not 1 is lower bound for r ?

Comment: @SophieClad, $\cos(\mathbb{R}) \subseteq [-1,1]$, so whenever $\sqrt{\cos(2\theta)}$ is real, it is $\le 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{\sqrt{\cos 2\theta}}^{1} r \ dr\  d\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$$

Comment: Thanks what is relation bw your answer and  comment of achille hui

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

The curve $r^2 = cos(2\theta)$ is completely inside of the region defined by the curve $r=1$.